# Lint Warning Expected positive indentation

Tags: c, for-loop, lint

I have an for loop which assign values to the members in a struct, depending upon the number(nr), but when i tried to Lint this piece of code it complains **Expected positive indentation** what does that mean ? what is wrong in this snippet

```
fun lint(U16 c, U16 d, U16 e, U16 nr)
{
struct* something[50]
for(U16 i=0; i<nr; i++) //Expected positive indentation
{
something[i] = alloc(sizeof(struct) *nr); //something[i] complains here
something[i] -> ab.c = c; //something[i] complains here
something[i] -> ab.d = d; //something[i] complains here
something[i] -> nrofthing = nr; //something[i] complains here
something[i] -> ab.e =e; //something[i] complains here
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: Assuming this was an example, I fixed obvious errors.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: but at the same time you removed the problem that `lint` was warning for!

Comment: @usr2564301,I didn't want to copy the code to my answer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: well, why not, if it makes your answer more clear. But *editing out* the problem that is asked about is an absolute no-no.

Answer (score 1):

I have "positively indented your code". That is what properly formatted code should look like: with every code block or loop, indent 4 spaces or 1 tab.

```
fun lint(U16 c, U16 d, U16 e, U16 nr)
{
    struct x *something[50];
    for(U16 i=0; i<nr; i++) //Expected positive indentation
    {
        something[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct x) *nr); //something[i] complains here
        something[i]->ab.c = c; //something[i] complains here
        something[i]->ab.d = d; //something[i] complains here
        something[i]->nrofthing = nr; //something[i] complains here
        something[i]->ab.e =e; //something[i] complains here
    }
}
```

With such indentation, it is easy to see where blocks, functions and loops start and end, making it easier to read the code.

Lint complained that you did not properly follow the rules on indentation.